# Extract date from datetime dictionary in django queryset

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-queryset

Spent way too much time on this so Ima ask,

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).values('send_date')
```

the result is this

```
<QuerySet [{'send_date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 30)}]>
```

Trying to get `2020, 9, 30`

I tried `sd=queryset.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, `sd=datetime.strptime(max(queryset.keys()),'%Y-%m-%d')` even tried `sd=queryset['send_date']`, `sd=queryset.get('send_date')`, `for key,value in queryset.items()` results into error `"queryset has no items() attr"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general queryset could have several items in it so you need to loop through it's values

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).values('send_date')
for date_value in queryset:
   print(date_value["send_date"])
```

if you sure that you will have only one value there, so you can get value as

```
queryset[0]["send_date"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doest it have to be a queryset as your filter parameter is the ID (which is unique I guess)?

If you know you're getting a single object, you could do :

```
MyModel.objects.get(id=id).send_date.strftime('%Y, %m, %d')
```

else if you want to keep the filter, you can get the dates in an array like this :

```
[send_date.strftime('%Y, %m, %d') for send_date in MyModel.objects.filter(id=id).values_list('send_date', flat=True)]
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I get "queryset has no send_date attr"

Comment: Did you replace `.filter()` by `.get()` ?

Comment: Can't remember really but the accepted answer solved it too, so I guess you both right.